# What is the fastest way of updating an ordered array of numbers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I need to calculate a 1d histogram that must be dynamically maintained and looked up frequently. One idea I had involves keeping an ordered array with the data (cause thus I can determine percentiles in O(1), and this suffices for quickly finding a histogram with non-uniform bins with the exactly same amount of points inside each bin).

So, is there a way that is less than O(N) to insert a number into an ordered array while keeping it ordered?

I guess the answer is very well known but I don't know a lot about algorithms (physicists doing numerical calculations rarely do).

Comment: If it's actually an array (as opposed to e.g. a linked-list), then the actual insertion itself will necessarily be *O(n)* (because you'll need to move all the subsequent elements along by one).  Searching to find the location to insert at can obviously be less than *O(n)*.

Comment: Is the data completely random or does it tend to follow some statistical equation? If the latter, you will get a better optimisation by taking this into account.   You will need the inverse function of the probability spread.

Comment: If you do not state the language you are using, you may need to state the running time of basic `array` operations, or else people will assume it is `O(1)` lookup, `O(index)` insertion, etc.; which may be what you want.

Comment: Are you storing integers or floating point numbers?

Comment: Hi. I'm storing floating point numbers, have no idea of how they are distributed (this is pretty much what my program will have to determine in the end) and I'm using C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, you could use a more flexible tree-like data structure. This would allow access, insertion and deletion in O(log) time and is also relatively easy to get ready-made from a library (ex.: C++'s STL map).

(Or a hash map...)

An ordered array with binary search does the same things as a tree, but is more rigid. It might probably be faster for acess and memory use but you will pay when having to insert or delete things in the middle (O(n) cost).

Note, however, that an ordered array might be enough for you: if your data points are often the same, you can mantain a list of pairs {key, count}, ordered by key, being able to quickly add another instance of an existing item (but still having to do more work to add a new item)

Answer (score 1):

You could use binary search. This is O(log(n)).
If you like to insert number x, then take the number in the middle of your array and compare it to x. if x is smaller then then take the number in the middle of the first half else the number in the middle of the second half and so on.

Comment: The search is *O(log n)*, the insertion will be *O(n)*.

Comment: This will work if the implementation of `array` allows `O(1)` insertion; arrays in C-like languages do not.

Comment: @ninjagecko: it's not an array in data structure terms, it's more like linked list, depends on implementation, of course

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a way that is less than O(N) to insert a number into an
>   ordered array while keeping it ordered?

Yes, you can use an array to implement a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) using arrays and do the insertion in O(log n) time. How?

Keep index 0 empty; index 1 = root; if node is the left child of parent node, index of node = 2 * index of parent node; if node is the right child of parent node, index of node = 2 * index of parent node + 1.

Insertion will thus be O(log n). Unfortunately, you might notice that the binary search tree for an ordered list might degenerate to a linear search if you don't balance the tree i.e. O(n), which is pointless. Here, you may have to implement a [red black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) to keep the height balanced. However, this is quite complicated, BUT insertion can be done with arrays in O(log n). Note that the array elements will no longer be ints; instead, they'll have to be objects with a colour attribute.

I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: The search is *O(log n)*, the insertion will be *O(n)*.

Comment: I think the insertion is still O(log n) because it requires O(log n) to find where to insert, then insertion is just O(1) from there to add to the correct index. Find more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)

Comment: Why implement using arrays at all? All you need is an iterable structure. Sounds like classic RB trees/AVL trees

Comment: @kyun the questioner asked: "So, is there a way that is less than O(N) to insert a number into an ordered array while keeping it ordered?".

Comment: @Dhruv Gairola I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform insertions in `O(1)` time if you rearrange your array as a bunch of linked-lists hanging off of each element:

```
keys = Array([0][1][2][3][4]......)
              a  c  b  e  f  .  .
              d  g     i  .  .  .
                 h     j  .
              |__|__|__|__|__|__|__/linked lists
```

There's also the strategy of keeping two datastructures at the same time, if your update workload supports it without increasing time-complexity of common operations.

Comment: But if I need to get who's the k-th element of the sequence, it would be O(k), wouldn't it?

Comment: @Rafael: you have to clarify exactly what you mean by "k-th element of the sequence". If you merely care about the order you received an element, it is `O(1)` (use hashtable). If you care about each linked list... I see no reason why you would care about the order of elements whose keys are equal, unless there's something you're not telling us. Even if you did, it is either `O(1)` if you use the two data structures side-by-side, or if you just used this data structure it would be `O(log(N))` (perform binary search, keeping track of how many elements are in each bin / each linked-list).

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason this demands an array? You need an data structure which keeps data ordered and allows you to insert quickly. Why not a binary search tree? Or better still, a red black tree. In C++, you could use the [Set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) structure in the Standard template library which is implemented as a red black tree. Gives you O(log(n)) insertion time and the ability to iterate over it like an array.